# Add text to text box if only one option is selected

Tags: javascript

Just trying to make it so when you select an option it will fill the text box,
it works but it makes it for all of the choices.

Form Code:

```js
function myFunction(e) {

  if (document.getElementById("room2").value = "Y32,UP5268,lp1345,gf2v,LP8862,u7402,GGP48,BTP3,UP5268,GGP38G,GFP242,L2040,Y0594")

  {
    document.getElementById("promo1").value = "dreamy"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("promo1").value = ""
  }

}
```

```html
<select name="room" id="room2" onchange="myFunction(event)">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="Y32,UP5268,lp1345,gf2v,LP8862,u7402,GGP48,BTP3,UP5268,GGP38G,GFP242,L2040,Y0594">1</option>
  <option value="I0K,I0KV,I0Q,IOQV,I1V,Y1V,Y2V,Y2LV,Y3V,Y4V">2</option>
  <option value="I0K,I0KV,I0Q,I0QV,I1V">- 3</option>
  <option value="Y1V,Y2V,Y2LV,Y3V,Y4V">- 4</option>

</select>
<input type="text" id="promo1">
```

It works but it changes

Comment: Can you show us the text box?

Comment: **`=` is not for comparison, it's for assigning.** Replace it by `==` (comparison without checking type) or `===` (comparison including type).

Comment: *"It works but it changes"* It changes what?

Comment: `document.getElementById("room2").value = "Y32,UP5268,lp1345,gf2v,LP8862,u7402,GGP48,BTP3,UP5268,GGP38G,GFP242,L2040,Y0594"` is always `true` if used as a condition because it is assigning that string to `document.getElementById("room2").value`, **not comparing it**.